# Python not writing to file (file closed)

Tags: python, tcp

I'm sending some code over TCP client (webserver), to raspberry PI's TCP server. Data is successfully sent, however, data is not written to .txt file (file has full permissions so anybody can write and read from it).

This is my TCP server code.

http://pastebin.com/CQ8thXhe

As you can see, I close the file, but the file remains empty. Data is successfully transmited since I get response on TCP client.

Comment: Are the data printed to the console _but_ not to the file?

Comment: Yes, data is successfully printed to console. Should I open file using UTF-8?

Comment: Alright, the problem is not with python.. I run the script on startup via rc.local file, it runs the script, but writing to file somehow isn't working.

Comment: define save directory( ex:`"/home/user/xxxx"` ) and file mode is `'wb'`

Comment: Basically, what the problem here was the line 31.. I had to change path to absolute path and wokred like a charm.